# mobile recharge integration in jQuery using PayPal?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, so my question may look weird but still I am asking.

I want to add "mobile recharge option" in a mobile app develop in jQuery, for that I would be needing PayPal integration for the mobile recharge. I am stuck at this functionality.
Any help in the form of a link/demo or sample code would be of great help for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its a complete stuck situation. havent tried anything for paypal integration. please guide through any demo code or a link would be of great help. also we need to create a demo account on paypal and do virtual transactions through our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal provide merchant account for owner and another for user. Check instruction in paypal site. To integrate it check demos there

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I doubt you'll get that all here. We're not going to write an entire app for you for free!

Your best bet is to read all the PayPal documentation thoroughly, including any API docs. That will help you create a demo account and work with the PayPal sandbox. Check https://developer.paypal.com/ for more information.

If you're really, really stuck and can't spare the time to learn the ropes then I'd suggest outsourcing the work.

Answer (score -1):

I suggust you use Stripe instead of paypal as its easier to integrate. And you can also use the Reloadly API here https://topupsapi.docs.apiary.io/#  to top up over 400 mobile operators in real time in your app / site.